# How does using the sauna in the Finnair business class lounge in Helsinki work?

Tags: finland, lounges, hel, finnair

If you're lucky enough to have access to the Finnair business class lounge in Helsinki airport, on the non-Schengen side, then the [lounge information has this gem in it](https://www.finnair.com/fi/gb/information-services/at-the-airport/lounges):

> Private shower suites and a Finnish sauna.

How does the sauna bit actually work in practice? Do you need to bring anything with you? Do you have to book? Is it really there? Is it any good?

Answer (score 30):

**Update December 2018** The Sauna is currently closed, as part of the wider Finnair non-Schengen lounge refurbishment. Lounge staff tell me it'll re-open lovely and refreshed in the spring

There really is a sauna in the lounge! It's only in the non-Schengen lounge. It's somewhat hidden, tucked away in the middle of the non-Schengen lounge complex, and anyone with [access to the lounge](https://www.finnair.com/fi/gb/information-services/at-the-airport/lounges) is able to use it. Location wise, it's next to the showers, in the middle between the normal and premium halves of the lounge. Follow signs for Showers and Sauna

You don't need to book, and you don't need to bring anything

There's only one small sauna, I'd say it could probably only hold about 6 comfortably. It's a single unisex sauna, and the signs request that you keep yourself covered up with the towels provided. As such, you don't need to have remembered your swimwear, though wearing swimwear is permitted (which I gather to be unusual for Finland!)

Just next to the entrance to the sauna, after the shower rooms, are two changing areas, one for each gender. Inside those you'll find a couple of lockers, with keys you can take into the sauna, a shower, and lots of towels.

I'm not much of a sauna connoisseur, but it was certainly a sauna, hot, and made for a refreshing pause during a layover in Helsinki! :)

Comment: You have a weird notion of "refreshing"

Comment: I am willing to upfront pay five euros if you find my a Finnish public sauna that even permits swimwear inside.

Comment: @Jan I'm not sure if your challenge was open to all, but [Löyly](http://www.loylyhelsinki.fi/en/saunas/) say ‘we respectfully request that swimming costumes are worn at all times’. (I found it rather surprising and disappointing, but I suppose they're aiming for the international market.) Anyway, if your 5€ offer was serious, you can send it to [Winternotprogramm Hamburg](https://www.winternotprogramm.de/spenden/) :)

Comment: @Pont I … never expected that, but I am a fair loser so see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm4Td.png